# One to Many bidirectional relationship not working in in memory HSQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hsqldb

I have a one to many mapping between city and people. One City can have many People.
After persisting data, on fetching the People object from hibernate  i m getting the city object also.City is the parent table/entity.
But on fetching the  city object using hibernate , the people object(set or list) is empty. The same code when tried against a MYSQL DB works fine. But while using HSQL in memory DB, i am facing the issue.
PFB the details:-

City entity:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITY")
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="CITY_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="CITY_NAME", nullable=false, unique= true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "city" )
    private Set<People> people = new HashSet<People>(0);
```

The People Entity:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="People")
public class People {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="People_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="People_NAME", nullable=false, unique= true)
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID")
    City city;
```

I will insert values to City table first.Example values:-("London")..and after persisting if teh generated cityid is "1001" 
Then will insert values to people table.Example values:-("John",1001)
Then on fetching the values for City object using hibernate , the people(set) is empty.
But if i fetch the values for People object, the city object has values.
PFb my xml file:-

```
<bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:TEST" />
            <property name="username" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory"                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />        
    </beans>
```

Is it a limitation of the in memory DB, or am i missing anything.
Any suggestions or link will be helpful

Comment: I guess this results in creation of only two tables in Database. right?? You do not have any relationship table in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a sample app to demonstrate this kind of relationship using hibernate, following is the code for that.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "COMP_NAME", length = 1000)
    private String companyName;
    @Column(name = "COMP_ADDRESS", length = 1000)
    private String companyAddress;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "company")
    private Employee emp;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Department> departments = new HashSet<Department>();

    public Set<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }

    public void setDepartments(Set<Department> departments) {
        this.departments = departments;
    }
```

Following is my Department.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String deptName;
    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
```

See that I didn't use @JoinColumn and this resulted in the creation of a relationship table, just remove @JoinColumn from your People class and you will get the collection of people from your City class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   It will create a third table right?Also the same example works for me when i use MYSQL, instead of HSQL in memory DB. And the original application in my case uses MYSQL and Junit uses in memory DB. So i dont have the option of changing the entity as it works fine with MYSQL .

Answer (score 0):

Check the transactions should be committed for all inserts before you select, and make sure the entities get flushed/cleared in the current context before you fetch, some times hibernate might be returning you the same entities which are not detached from the current persistence context, hope this helps!!